# Custom gems in Puppet Provider

Tags: puppet, ruby, puppet-agent

I am running Puppet 3.7 and I have the following issue:

Installed the nokogiri gem on the agents with pe_gem. Wrote a custom provider that does `require 'nokogiri'` at the top.

The Puppet run "sometimes" fails with "Unable to load 'nokogiri'" error from Ruby autoloader.

The thing is - it works the first time it gets the provider from the Puppet master. All subsequent runs fail.

My guess is that somehow there is something loaded before my provider that makes it work, when it does.

Did anyone else experience this or think about what can it be?

Comment: Could you add the Puppet Error message? What does the debug mode say? What happens if you install the gem without Puppet? Perhaps the issue is caused by the custom gem itself. Could you install the gem and when it is installed, install it again and again. Does the same issue occur?